# c++ GetCurrentThemeName return empty value for Classic windows themes

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

When I call `GetCurrentThemeName()` for Windows 7 Basic style, I get "C:\windows\resources\Themes\Aero\Aero.msstyles", but when I call it for Windows Classic style or Windows High Contrast style, I get empty sting.

Is it expected?

How can I distinguish Windows Classic style from Windows High Contrast style in my C++ application?

Thanks,
Zhenya

Comment: Windows Classic style is not a theme, it's an absence of themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Windows Classic and High Contrast will *disable* themes so an empty string is entirely expected.

- Use GetThemeAppProperties() to check if theming is enabled, check for STAP_ALLOW_CONTROLS
- Use SystemParametersInfo with SPI_GETHIGHCONTRAST to check if high contrast is enabled.